# If $S = \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) \neq0\}$ and $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, why is the complement of $S$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If the set $S = \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) \neq0\}$ and $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, why is the complement of $S$ closed? I am unable to see why, is this due to finiteness? Thanks!

Comment: @T.Bongers that would imply that $S^c$ is open (preimage of open set under continuous function is open)

Comment: @DanZimm Right, I had $S$ and $S^c$ backwards. Since $S = f^{-1}(\{0\}^c)$ is the preimage of an open set, $S$ is open.

Comment: @T.Bongers how do you find that $\{0\}^c$ is open when working under $[0,1]$; I see that $1 \in \{0\}^c$ but it isn't an interior point.

Comment: The domain is $[0,1]$, but the range is (I assume) $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$; that's the topology to study $\{0\}^c$ in. (And although it's not actually relevent, $(0,1]$ is relatively open in the usual topology on $[0,1]$).

Comment: @T.Bongers ah that would be my mis-reading of the question! And yes again I realized once I posted that it was a silly question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to work with proving that $S$ is in fact open (since $S$ is open $\iff$ $S^c$ is closed). Assume for contradiction that it is not open, then $\exists \; p \in S$ so that
\begin{equation}
\forall \; \epsilon > 0 \; (p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon) \not\subset S \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
However note that since $p \in S$ we have that $f(p) \neq 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, specifically at $p$, we then have that
$$
\forall \; \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \; \delta > 0 \; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } | x - p | < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon
$$
Specifically with $\epsilon = | f(p) / 2 |$ we have that
$$
\exists \; \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } | x - p | < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(p)| < |f(p)/2|
$$
Clearly then $\forall x$ that this is true $f(x) \neq 0$ (why?) so that the set of $x \in [0,1]$ so that $| x - p | < \delta$ is a *nonempty* subset of $S$ thus contradicting (1).

So then $S$ is open and $S^c$ is closed.

EDIT: The above does not work for we do not have the guarantee that the set of $x \in [0,1]$ so that $| x - p | < \delta$ is an open subset of $S$. For example, if $p = 1$ then it surely won't be an open subset. I'm sure there's a technical detail I'm missing here. I will keep this up for a few minutes while I think about it. An alternative proof is as follows and was posted in the comments (unsure why the commenter didn't post it as an answer):

We have that $\{0\}^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is continuous we have that
$f^{-1}(\{0\}^c)$ is open which is exactly $S$ so that the compliment is closed.

EDIT$^2$: Well it looks like both proofs actually need to work in the space of $[0,1]$ so that our sets are relatively open. That is $\{0\}^c$ is relatively open in $[0,1]$ so the above follows. My original proof is valid since it's continuous in $[0,1]$ and thus working in the space $[0,1]$ we have that the set of $x \in [0,1]$ so that $| x - p | < \delta$ is a relatively open set in $[0,1]$.

Hope this helps, sorry for the struggles and edits!